# Why wont my sqlite database create although I have implemented the same process in a previous application?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.application.sweetiean.stlmaintenance, PID: 7148
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Base": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Maintenance Base Data Table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Date TEXT, Sysaid Id TEXT, Task Type TEXT, Customer TEXT, Site Id TEXT, Address TEXT, Region TEXT, Phone TEXT, E-Mail TEXT, Location Coordinates TEXT, STL Rep Name TEXT, STL Rep Position TEXT, STL Rep Signature TEXT, Client Rep Name TEXT, Client Rep Position TEXT, Client Rep Signature TEXT);
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:690)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1806)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1737)
at com.application.sweetiean.stlmaintenance.MaintenanceAppDB$DbHelper.onCreate(MaintenanceAppDB.java:280)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
at com.application.sweetiean.stlmaintenance.MaintenanceAppDB.openForRead(MaintenanceAppDB.java:423)
at com.application.sweetiean.stlservicing.Serv_OverviewFragment.init(Serv_OverviewFragment.java:66)
at com.application.sweetiean.stlservicing.Serv_OverviewFragment.onCreateView(Serv_OverviewFragment.java:57)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17327)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:582)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:649)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17327)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17327)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17327)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17327)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5363)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
at android.view.View.
```

Above is the error log I get when my application tries to create the data base. 
Below is the database class:

```
package com.application.sweetiean.stlmaintenance;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by sweetiean on 11/21/2015.
 */
public class MaintenanceAppDB {

private DbHelper maintenanceAppHelper;
private final Context maintenanceAppContext;
private SQLiteDatabase maintenanceAppDatabase;

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "maintenance_app_db";

private static final String TABLE_MAIN_INFO = "Maintenance Base Data Table";
private static final String TABLE_MAIN_TASK = "Task Table";
private static final String TABLE_MAIN_IMAGES = "Images";

public static final String TABLE_SERV_INFO = "Service Base Data Table";
private static final String TABLE_SERV_SERVICING = "Servicing Table";
private static final String TABLE_SERV_REPLACEMENT = "Replacement Table";

//COMMON FIELDS
public static final String ROW_ID = "_id";
public static final String SYSAID_ID = "Sysaid Id";
public static final String TASK_TYPE = "Task Type";
public static final String CUSTOMER = "Customer";
public static final String SITE_ID = "Site Id";
public static final String ADDRESS = "Address";
public static final String REGION = "Region";
public static final String LOCATION = "Location Coordinates";
public static final String STL_REP_NAME = "STL Rep Name";
public static final String STL_REP_POST = "STL Rep Position";
public static final String STL_REP_SIGN = "STL Rep Signature";
public static final String CLIENT_REP_NAME = "Client Rep Name";
public static final String CLIENT_REP_POST = "Client Rep Position";
public static final String CLIENT_REP_SIGN = "Client Rep Signature";
public static final String REMARKS = "Remarks";
public static final String DATE = "Date";

//MAINTENANCE FIELDS
public static final String PHONE = "Phone";
public static final String EMAIL = "E-Mail";
public static final String INVENTORY = "Inventory";
public static final String GEN_HOURS = "GenSet Run Hours";
public static final String BATTERY_VOLT = "Battery Voltage";
public static final String MAINTENANCE_TYPE = "Maintenance Type";
public static final String QUANTITY = "Quantity";

public long createBaseDataRecord(String sql_date, String sql_sysaid, String sql_taskType, String sql_customer,
                                 String sql_siteId, String sql_address, String sql_region, String sql_phone,
                                 String sql_email, String sql_location, String sql_stlRepName, String sql_stlRepPost,
                                 String sql_stlRepSign, String sql_clientRepName, String sql_clientRepPost,
                                 String sql_clientRepSign) {

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(DATE, sql_date);
    cv.put(SYSAID_ID, sql_sysaid);
    cv.put(TASK_TYPE, sql_taskType);
    cv.put(CUSTOMER, sql_customer);
    cv.put(SITE_ID, sql_siteId);
    cv.put(ADDRESS, sql_address);
    cv.put(REGION, sql_region);
    cv.put(PHONE, sql_phone);
    cv.put(EMAIL, sql_email);
    cv.put(LOCATION, sql_location);
    cv.put(STL_REP_NAME, sql_stlRepName);
    cv.put(STL_REP_POST, sql_stlRepPost);
    cv.put(STL_REP_SIGN, sql_stlRepSign);
    cv.put(CLIENT_REP_NAME, sql_clientRepName);
    cv.put(CLIENT_REP_POST, sql_clientRepPost);
    cv.put(CLIENT_REP_SIGN, sql_clientRepSign);

    return maintenanceAppDatabase.insert(TABLE_MAIN_INFO, null, cv);
}

private class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        //MAINTENANCE TABLES
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MAIN_INFO + " ("
                + ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + DATE + " TEXT, "
                + SYSAID_ID + " TEXT, "
                + TASK_TYPE + " TEXT, "
                + CUSTOMER + " TEXT, "
                + SITE_ID + " TEXT, "
                + ADDRESS + " TEXT, "
                + REGION + " TEXT, "
                + PHONE + " TEXT, "
                + EMAIL + " TEXT, "
                + LOCATION + " TEXT, "
                + STL_REP_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + STL_REP_POST + " TEXT, "
                + STL_REP_SIGN + " TEXT, "
                + CLIENT_REP_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + CLIENT_REP_POST + " TEXT, "
                + CLIENT_REP_SIGN + " TEXT);"

        );


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}

public MaintenanceAppDB(Context c){
    maintenanceAppContext = c;
}


public SQLiteDatabase openForRead(){
    maintenanceAppHelper = new DbHelper(maintenanceAppContext);
    maintenanceAppDatabase = maintenanceAppHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    return maintenanceAppDatabase;
}

public void close(){
    maintenanceAppHelper.close();
}
}
```

And here is the fragment where I try to read from the database into a list view

```
package com.application.sweetiean.stlservicing;


import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.application.sweetiean.stlmaintenance.MaintenanceAppDB;
import com.application.sweetiean.stlmaintenance.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Serv_OverviewFragment extends Fragment {

View view;
ListView overview_display;
// Arraylist for overviews
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> overList;
private ArrayList<String> sysid;
private ArrayList<String> engName;
private ArrayList<String> taskType;
private ArrayList<String> date;
private MaintenanceAppDB db1;
private SQLiteDatabase sqldb;
private Serv_OverviewAdapter adapter;



public Serv_OverviewFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_serv__overview, container, false);
    init();
    return view;
}

public void init(){

    overview_display = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.displayListView);

    db1 = new MaintenanceAppDB(this.getActivity());
    sqldb = db1.openForRead();
    if (sqldb.isOpen()) {
        Cursor cursor = sqldb.query(MaintenanceAppDB.TABLE_SERV_INFO,
                new String[]{MaintenanceAppDB.SYSAID_ID, MaintenanceAppDB.TASK_TYPE, MaintenanceAppDB.STL_REP_NAME, MaintenanceAppDB.DATE}, null, null, null, null, null);

        overList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        sysid = new ArrayList<String>();
        date = new ArrayList<String>();
        engName = new ArrayList<String>();
        taskType = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                sysid.add(cursor.getString(0));
                taskType.add(cursor.getString(1));
                engName.add(cursor.getString(2));
                date.add(cursor.getString(3));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            overList.add(sysid);
            overList.add(taskType);
            overList.add(engName);
            overList.add(date);

        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    if (overList.size() != 0) {
        adapter = new Serv_OverviewAdapter(this.getActivity(), overList);
        overview_display.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    //listview context menu
    registerForContextMenu(overview_display);//takes listview as argument. can take any view tho
}


}
```

So I have tried replacing the spaces in the table names with underscores, I have made them all lower case but the app still crashes at onCreate.

Comment: Maintenance Base Data is that your table name ? I doubt spaces are allowed in table names. Remove the space from all  your table names, probably that would help.

Comment: @Triode it is not advisable to have spaces in the table names but I replaced those spaces with underscores and still got the same error

Comment: I can still see some spaces in your column names as well can you try removing them all ?

Comment: @Triode yes sure I have done that now and this is the current error log message `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "-": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE Maintenance_Base_Data_Table (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Date TEXT, Sysaid_Id TEXT, Task_Type TEXT, Customer TEXT, Site_Id TEXT, Address TEXT, Region TEXT, Phone TEXT, E-Mail TEXT, Location_Coordinates TEXT, STL_Rep_Name TEXT, STL_Rep_Position TEXT, STL_Rep_Signature TEXT, Client_Rep_Name TEXT, Client_Rep_Position TEXT, Client_Rep_Signature TEXT);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use E_Mail instead of E-Mail because '-' is not supposed to be in column name.

Comment: When I made this correction, the error log flagged a similar error in the "500GB" field and so I corrected that and all the other table names with numbers "_500GB". The application does not crash anymore. I guess I can move on now.

Comment: Yes . You you can go on now. DO consult if there still is any problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Sysaid_Id instead of Sysaid Id